# How to know the next date of a given date by c++?

Tags: c++

I want to know the next date of a given date.

my input's type is `int`, For example:

when i input `20220623`, i need output `20220624`

I think it can not be implemented by pure arithmetric operation.

I googled this, but can't find a good method.

I perfer not to do this by self handling method, better using the standard library, because that will be fast and reliable.

So, is there any usable method in c++ standard library can use to do date arithmetric operation?

Comment: A date should usually not be represented by the int number used by humans. And depending of countries or cultures, `20220604` could mean 4th of June in 2022 or 6th of April in 2022.

Comment: You can just use the standard library https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day/year_month_day

Comment: splitting int into substrings and handling constraints for these year month and days would give you better understanding